# Specifying web favicon that's different from app icon

Tags: android, google-chrome, meteor, google-chrome-app, favicon

I've got a standard ICO file in my root directory. It worked as expected.

Upon making my Meteor webapp `mobile-web-app-capable` for Chrome/Android and adding the necessary icons to [its required manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen), my original web favicon is now showing the app icon instead.

I want separate icons for web favicon and for app home screens. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be solved by specifying the favicon after the Chrome mobile web app meta code. Specifically:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
...
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
```

Simple.